# RichTextEditor adf component ,help needed

Tags: oracle-adf, spell-checking

I want to used adf richtexteditor component and implement below two things :

1. A character counter [Number of character an user enters dynamically]
   2.spell check

I am using 11.1.1.6 Jdev version.

Comment: Anyone who could help me here ??
How do I call javascript onKeypress event on richtext editor adf component??

Answer (score 0):

You can use  to hook javascript function call to events like keyPress, mouseClick. Some thing like:

```
<af:resource type="javascript">
  function doSomething(){ }
</af:resource>
<af:richTextEditor>
  <af:clientListener method="doSomething" type="keyPress"/>
</af:richTextEditor>
```

For more details visit: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24382_01/web.1112/e16181/af_arch.htm